# Having problems with my Card Game in java

Tags: java

This is my code, my questions is with my deal method, how do I get it to inclement the to a different number every time I call it and also how to create a Boolean method. This is my code, my questions is with my deal method, how do I get it to inclement the to a different number every time I call it and also how to create a Boolean method.

```
package Card;

import java.util.Random;

/**
*
* @author Mr. Pierre
*/

public class Card {

    private int SuitRank;
    private int CardRank;
    private String cardValue;

    //My constructor
    public Card()
    {
        SuitRank=1;
        CardRank=2;
    }

    //My deal method
    void dealCard()
    {   
        SuitRank++;

        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        int SuitRank = randomGenerator.nextInt(4)+1;

        CardRank++;

        Random randomGenerator1 = new Random();
        int CardRank= randomGenerator1.nextInt(13)+2;
    }

    //My compare method
    public int compare(Card otherCard)
    {
        if (otherCard.getCardRank() > CardRank)
            return  1;

        if (otherCard.getCardRank() == CardRank)
        {
            if (otherCard.getSuitRank() > SuitRank)
                return 1;
            if (otherCard.getSuitRank()< SuitRank)
            return -1;
            if (otherCard.getSuitRank()==SuitRank)
                return 0;
        }

        if (otherCard.getCardRank() < CardRank)
            return  -1;

        return CardRank;
    }

    //my Get suitrank method
    public int getSuitRank()
    {
        SuitRank++;
        return SuitRank;
    }

    public String  getSuitName ()    
    {
        String SuitName="";
        if( SuitRank == 1){
            SuitName = "Clubs";
        }
        else if(SuitRank == 2){
            SuitName = "Diamonds";
        }
        else if(SuitRank == 3){
            SuitName = "Hearts";
        }
        else if(SuitRank == 4){
            SuitName = "Spades";
        }

        return SuitName;
    }

    public int getCardRank ()
    {
        return CardRank;
    }

    public String getCardName ()
    {
        String CardName="";
        if(CardRank==2){
            CardName="Duce";
        }
        else if(CardRank==3){
            CardName="Three";
        }
        else if(CardRank==3){
            CardName="Three";
        }
        else if(CardRank==4){
            CardName="Four";
        }
        else if(CardRank==5){
            CardName="Five";
        }
        else if(CardRank==6){
            CardName="Six";
        }
        else if(CardRank==7){
            CardName="Seven";
        }
        else if(CardRank==8){
            CardName="Eight";
        }
        else if(CardRank==9){
            CardName="Nine";
        }
        else if(CardRank==10){
            CardName="Ten";
        }
        else if(CardRank==11){
            CardName="Jack";
        }
        else if(CardRank==12){
            CardName="Queen";
        }
        else if(CardRank==13){
            CardName="King";
        }
        else if(CardRank==14){
            CardName="Ace";
        }

        return CardName;
    }

    public String  toString()
    {
        return getCardName()+ " of " +getSuitName();
    }  
}
```

Comment: have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html

Comment: Get what to increment? I see you're already using the ++ operator so what exactly do you want to increment to another number? Also you can create a boolean function just like you created your other functions.

`public boolean foo() {return true;}`

Comment: Inclement is clearly not the word you meant. You used it twice though. Do you mean increment?

Answer (score 1):

```
int SuitRank = randomGenerator.nextInt(4)+1;
```

The `int` means you're creating a local variable instead of modyfying a class member. Also, why are you calling `SuitRank++` if you're planning to set `SuitRank` to a random value right away? Same applies to `CardRank`.

As for the Boolean method - it's just `public Boolean method(...)`.